# XSLT variable problems

Tags: xml, xslt, variables

I've just started to get to now xslt, and xml and i can't seem to solve my problem which should be in my homework soon.
This is the part i had at the start:

```
    <p>
    <xsl:text>Date: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/vers/fejlec/ido/ev"/>.
        <xsl:value-of select="/vers/fejlec/ido/honap"/>.
    </p>
```

The third line gives me a value of 2
In my exercise it should give February instead of 2 (in the example its Hungarian).

So i did this:

```
   <p>
   <xsl:text>Dátum: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/vers/fejlec/ido/ev"/>.
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

   <xsl:variable name="month">
      <xsl:value-of select="/vers/fejlec/ido/honap"/>
   </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="monthinstring">
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$month=1">januar</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=2">februar</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=3">marcius</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=4">aprilis</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=5">majus</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=6">junius</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=7">julius</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=8">augusztus</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=9">szeptember</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=10">oktober</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=11">november</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$month=12">december</xsl:when>
       </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:text> $monthinstring </xsl:text>

    </p>
```

Unfortunately i cant print out nor month, nor monthinstring, i tried it more vaw, but it's just not working.

Comment: Good job mentioning that this is homework.  In future please also use the `homework` tag (for those who have it filtered.)

Comment: +1 for a great first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `xsl:value-of`.

Change this:

```
<xsl:text> $monthinstring </xsl:text>
```

To this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$monthinstring"/>
```

or this if you need to preserve the white-space before/after `$monthinstring`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',$monthinstring,' ')"/>
```